# Looking for orthogonal matrices $X$ and $Y$ that make $XAY$ be partitioned matrix with identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $m\times n$ matrix be $A$. Rank of $A$ is $n$, where $n \leq m$, so $A$ is a full-column matrix.

The rank of $A$ is $n$ if and only if there exists an invertible $m\times m$ matrix $X$ and $n \times n$ invertible matrix $Y$ that satisfy

$XAY=\begin{pmatrix}
I_n\\ 
0_{(m-n)\times n}
\end{pmatrix}$

More specifically, the above fact is demonstrated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)

I'm wondering if there exists $X$ and $Y$ such that $X'X=I_m$ and $Y'Y=I_n$, for any $A$. If it doesn't hold for any $A$, then what condition of $A$ will lead $X$ and $Y$ to satisfy $X'X=I_m$ and $Y'Y=I_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is readily addressed using singular value decomposition (SVD).  $\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} }$ and $\underline {\overline {\bf{Y}} }$ will be orthogonal if and only if the $n$ singular values of $\underline {\overline {\bf{A}} }$ are all unity, which then implies that
$${\underline {\overline {\bf{A}} } ^T}\underline {\overline {\bf{A}} }  = {\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } _{\left[ n \right]}}$$

The additional details:  $\underline {\overline {\bf{A}} }$ can always be written as
$$\underline {\overline {\bf{A}} }  = {\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } ^T}\underline {\overline {\bf{S}} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{Y}} } ^T}$$
where $\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} }$ and $\underline {\overline {\bf{Y}} }$ are the desired orthogonal matrices.  Hence
$$\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{A}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{Y}} }  = \left( {\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}} \right)\underline {\overline {\bf{S}} } \,\left( {{{\underline {\overline {\bf{Y}} } }^T}\underline {\overline {\bf{Y}} } } \right) = \underline {\overline {\bf{S}} }$$
Since the singular values of the SVD are unique (other than their ordering), for your situation you require
$$\underline {\overline {\bf{S}} }  = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{s_1}}& \cdots &0\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0& \cdots &{{s_n}}
\end{array}} \right]}\\
{\underline {\overline {\bf{0}} } }
\end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } }_{\left[ n \right]}}}\\
{\underline {\overline {\bf{0}} } }
\end{array}} \right]$$
Then
$${\underline {\overline {\bf{A}} } ^T}\underline {\overline {\bf{A}} }  = \underline {\overline {\bf{Y}} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{S}} } ^T}\left( {\,\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}} \right)\underline {\overline {\bf{S}} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{Y}} } ^T} = \underline {\overline {\bf{Y}} } \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } }_{\left[ n \right]}}}&{\underline {\overline {\bf{0}} } }
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } }_{\left[ n \right]}}}\\
{\underline {\overline {\bf{0}} } }
\end{array}} \right]{\underline {\overline {\bf{Y}} } ^T} = \underline {\overline {\bf{Y}} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{Y}} } ^T} = {\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } _{\left[ n \right]}}$$

Comment: Using singular value decomposition, $A$ can be decomposed as $A_{m\times n} = U_{m\times m} S_{m\times n} V_{n\times n}$ where $U'U=I_m$ and $V'V=I_n$. Can you help me how we can prove that $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal iff $n$ singular values of $A$ are all unity?